# Autenticação AzureAD e Identity no mesmo Projeto

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

***Aplicação:*** Construída em .NET Core 2.2

É possível ter duas formas de autenticação em um único projeto C# ? Me encontrei no seguinte cenário:

1 - Os usuários que são colaboradores da empresa utilizam o AzureAd para realizar a autenticação, e este funciona adequadamente;

2 - Os usuários que não são colaboradores, mas parceiros, devem realizar a autenticação de outra forma que não seja via Azure.

**PS: Não tenho a opção de criar usuários Usuários Guest no AzureAD.**

3 - Tanto os colaboradores, quanto os parceiros acessam a mesma aplicação.

Eu tentei adicionar uma nova forma de autenticação no StartUp da Aplicação, mas não sei definir se é a melhor estratégia. O trecho abaixo é a autenticação do AzureAD, que está OK.

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctxt =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },
                OnMessageReceived = async ctxt =>
                {
                    await Task.Yield();
                },
                OnTicketReceived = async ctxt =>
                {
                    if (ctxt.Principal.Identity is ClaimsIdentity identity)
                    {
                        //alguma funcionalidade
                    }

                    await Task.Yield();
                },
            };
        });
```

Dei uma lida também sobre realizar a criação de Usuários via Identity, mas fiquei na dúvida se a aplicação entenderá onde realizar a verificação do User.Identity, se no AzureAD ou em outro schema de autenticação.

```
Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
```

Alguém já passou por algo semelhante ?

Answer (score 0):

Após algumas pesquisas, cheguei a seguinte solução:

**Documentação:**
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Para as features que serão autenticadas para "parceiros" indicados na pergunta, optei por autenticação via Cookies.

O primeiro passo é definir os Schemas de autenticação que sua aplicação usuará. No meu caso, em ConfigureServices no Startup.cs da minha WebApp, ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Código inicial omitido...

    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
        sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }
    )
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy = policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        options.DefaultPolicy = policy.Build();
    });
}
```

Feito isso, adicionaremos a autorização. Aqui ele adiciona as policys para uma forma de autenticação ou outra:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Código inicial omitido...

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        policy = policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        options.DefaultPolicy = policy.Build();
    });
}
```

E para autenticar os usuários via Cookies, criei um Controller que criará meu Identity in runtime. Nesse caso, observe a decoração [AllowAnonymous], para que o escopo da autenticação seja ignorado para essa Action.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    //Dados vindos de um Post Qualquer...
    string email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Email"]) ? string.Empty : Request.Form["Email"].ToString();
    string senha = CloudlabFunctions.GetHashMd5(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["Password"]) ? string.Empty : Request.Form["Password"].ToString());

    Usuario ClasseDoUsuario = null;

    using (BusUsuario Bus = new BusUsuario(_config))
    {
        ClasseDoUsuario = Bus.GetUsuario(email, senha);
    }

    if (ClasseDoUsuario != null)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, ClasseDoUsuario.Nome),
                    new Claim("Endereco", ClasseDoUsuario.Endereco),
                    new Claim("Cep", ClasseDoUsuario.Cep),

                    //E outras Claims que você precisar.
                };

        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            //Pode-se adicionar propriedades de autenticação específicas, como por exemplo, se o cookie é peristente entre sessões, data de expiração, se permite atualização, etc.
        };

        ClaimsPrincipal Usuario = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);

        Task res = HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Usuario, authProperties);
        res.Wait();


        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect("PaginaDeErroQualquer");
    }
}
```

É mais ou menos esse o caminho das pedras.

Abçs !